# Does date lie with in range ? How to compare datetime Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi I am trying to establish if an Exit date lies within a week start and week end date of two data frames.

```
daterange_df = pd.DataFrame(user_dates)
daterange_df['week_start'] = pd.to_datetime(daterange_df['week_start'])
daterange_df['week_end'] = pd.to_datetime(daterange_df['week_end'])

print(daterange_df)
```

The data is:

```
week_start     week_end
0 2019-05-01   2019-05-08
1 2019-05-08   2019-05-15
2 2019-05-15   2019-05-22    
3 2019-05-22   2019-05-29
4 2019-05-29   2019-06-05
```

I have a generated week start and week end dates and I have to establish the number of instances where the given Exit dates below lie between the week ranges.

```
parking_master = pd.read_csv(r'\\fppoevsdfs01. csv',header=None, names =['Booking_Ref','Entry_Date','Exit_Date','Product_Name','Duration','Leadtime', 'Parking_Gross','Parking_Net'] )
parking_master['Exit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(parking_master['Exit_Date'])
```

Data:

```
470   2019-05-19
471   2019-05-27    
472   2019-05-26
473   2019-05-26
474   2019-05-28
475   2019-05-27
476   2019-05-27
477   2019-05-22
478   2019-05-18
479   2019-05-25
480   2019-05-25
481   2019-05-17
482   2019-05-25
483   2019-05-26
484   2019-05-27
485   2019-05-27
486   2019-05-18
487   2019-05-25
488   2019-05-26
489   2019-05-19
490   2019-05-23
491   2019-05-27
492   2019-05-27
493   2019-05-27
494   2019-05-27
495   2019-05-17
496   2019-05-20
497   2019-05-27
498   2019-05-26
499   2019-05-27

Name: Exit_Date, Length: 500, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: can only compare identicall-labeled Series objects

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does the statement that is generating the ValueError look like? What is the type() of the operands being used in it?

Comment: Okay so i'm trying to add total sales if the Exit date lies with in the range so the code i'm using is 


````Total_Sales =0
if daterange_df['week_start'] <= parking_master['Exit_Date'] <= 
  daterange_df['week_end'] :
  Total_Sales=+parking_master['Parking_Net']
print(Total_Sales)

so I guess is Boolean operators. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to read the flowed text, especially in Python. Please edit your question to show the program. Identify the exact line that triggers the exception (the line number should be in your error message, identifying which line). 

Make sure you provide the types. You can use, for example:

print(type(daterange_df['week_start'])) 

to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595857/how-to-check-if-date-lies-within-week-range - this should help. Thanks